# Multiply array of different size

Tags: python, numpy

Multiply array of different size.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

b = np.array([1,2,3])

print a*b
```

Ofcourse error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (3,)
```

Expected result is np.array([1,4,9,0,0])

How to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> b = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> b.resize(a.shape)
>>> a * b
array([1, 4, 9, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Append a zero array to the smaller array depending on the difference in size:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
b = np.array([1,2,3])

diff = len(a) - len(b)

c = np.append(b, np.zeros(diff))

print a*c
```

Comment: you are missing size check

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct but to do it without creating a temporary in one line

```
c=np.append(a,np.zeros(0 if (len(b) - len(a))<0 else (len(b) - len(a))))*np.append(b,np.zeros(0 if (len(a) - len(b))<0 else (len(a) - len(b))))
```